# How to convert an array (from api) to values and compare them?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to fetch 2 API lists and compare their values.

For example:

```
const FirstList= [{
"Games": 5
"Wis": 5
"Loses": 5
}]

const SecondList= [{
"Games": 3
"Wis": 6
"Loses": 3
}]
```

I want to compare these two and the one with the bigger value gets highlighted with red color.

I fetch these lists to `const [list, setList] = useState([])`
I don't know how to compare the values.

Comment: Which value should be bigger?

Comment: compare object name each other, list1[0]["Games"] with list2[0]["Games"]

Comment: Are there only two arrays and both with single object and same keys? 
Can you share the code where data is shown and need to be highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

You can write as `FirstList[0]["Games"]==SecondList[0]["Games"]`